# Angular 2 Custom validator that depends on another form control

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm trying to make a custom validator for my FormControl `mealType`

If my FormControl `category` has a value and `mealType` does not, `mealType` should be invalid.

If `category` has no value, `mealType` should be valid.

I'm getting a console error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

code:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [null, this.validateMealType],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}

validateMealType() {
    if (this.findForm.get('categories').value) {
        if (this.findForm.get('mealTypes').value) {
            var mealTypeError = false;
        } else {
            var mealTypeError = true;
        }
    } else {
        var mealTypeError = false;
    }

    return mealTypeError ? null : {
        error: true
    }
}
```

It is my form that is undefined.

How do I resolve this?

Trying this:

```
validateMealType(categoryControl: FormControl, mealTypeControl: FormControl) {
    if (categoryControl.value) {
        if (!mealTypeControl.value) {
            var mealTypeError = true;
        } else {
            var mealTypeError = false;
        }
    } else {
        var mealTypeError = false;
    }

    return mealTypeError ? null : {
        error: true
    }
}
```

but it causes:

> Error in
>   app/find-page/subcomponents/find-page/find-form.component.html:36:5
>   caused by: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined

trying this:

```
class MealTypeValidator {

    constructor(private categoryFormControl: FormControl) { }

    mealTypeValidator(control: FormControl): { [error: string]: any } {
        if (this.categoryFormControl.value) {
            if (!control.value) {
                return { error: true };
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then in my form component:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [null, new MealTypeValidator(this.findForm.get('categories').mealTypeValidator()],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}
```

but I have compilation errors. How do I get this right? I think i'm just a bit off on both the validation class I made and the usage of it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are one step closer.

You need to attach your custom validator to the `FormGroup` instead, because it needs to know two `FormControl` (`categories` and `mealTypes`), so attaching to `FormGroup` will give the validator more broad view and access to the entire `FormControl`

To achieve that, change your `ngOnInit` to

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = new FormGroup({
        mealTypes : new FormControl(null, Validators.Required),
        categories : new FormControl(null)
        // others form control here
    }, validateMealType); // <-- see here is your custom function
}
```

On above code, you actually have to use `FormGroup` constructor instead of `FormBuilder`, so you can attach your custom validation in the parameters. Also, move your custom validator outside the component class.

Take a look at this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2xMxtEpJLvBnsfcdCil7?p=preview) to get more insight for your specific case here.

Comment: Is it possible to have multiple formgroup validators? What if i want another validator besides just "validateMealType" that depends on multiple controls.

Comment: @JoshuaJLIVEWilliams The [FormGroup constructor](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#constructor()) can take a single ValidatorFn (as above), an array of the same or an AbstractControlOptions object that has named properties with the prior mention validator function or array of functions, like: `{validators: validateMealType}`

Comment: Had to go for the object @jmmygoggle mentioned. Pure function as shown in the solution is not called in my case. `ng-version="9.1.9"`

Answer (score 10):

You can navigate your way through the control and its parent form group to another control:

```
example(): ValidatorFn {
     return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
         const forbidden = control.value < control.parent.controls["anotherControl"].value;
         return forbidden ? { forbidden: { message: "Custom message" } } : null;
     };
}
```

Add the above as a function inside your component and declare this validator to your form control:

```
formGroup = new FormGroup({
    //..
    targetControl: new FormControl("", [this.example()]),
    anotherControl: new FormControl("")
    //..
});
```

Comment: This works pretty well but I had to check to see if parent existed before accessing the other control. Also control.parent.get('anotherControl') will keep tslint from yelling at you.

Answer (score 5):

The solution proposed by @Michael worked for me with a minor change for the Angular 4.

In the validation function, I needed to change the parameter type from AbstractControl to FormGroup because the AbstractControl in this version does not contain the controls collection.

```
function validateEqual(form: FormGroup): { [key: string]: boolean } {
  const senha = form.controls['novaSenha'];
  const confirmacaoSenha = form.controls['confirmacaoNovaSenha'];

  if (senha != undefined && confirmacaoSenha != undefined) {
    const senhaValue = senha.value;
    const confirmacaoSenhaValue = confirmacaoSenha.value;

    if (senhaValue !== confirmacaoSenhaValue) {
        return { 'A senha e a confirmação não coincidem.': true};
    }

    return null;
  }
}
```

Thanks too, @Ariel who founds this post.

Comment: Instead of form.controls['control_name'] you can use form.get('control_name') but when you specify exact input type it looks cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

> mealTypes: [null, new MealTypeValidator(this.findForm.get('categories').mealTypeValidator()]

- You can't reference to formGroup inside builder clause.

But we can get parent from control and using optional operator we can reference to value and get another control value then compare whatever logic we need.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.findForm = this.formBuilder.group({
        categories: [null, Validators.required],
        mealTypes: [null, this.mealTypeValidator()],
        distanceNumber: null,
        distanceUnit: 'kilometers',
        keywords: null,
    });
}

mealTypeValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        return control.parent?.value.categories && !control.value
            ? { forbidden: { message: 'MealType should have a type under category!' } }
            : null;
    };
}
```

Comment: This solution works perfectly with FormBuilder.