# prevent entering same value for two fields angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular, validation

I need to prevent entering same value for two different text boxes

this is my code.

```
<input type="text"  required [(ngModel)]="passwordModel.oldPassword" name="oldPassword" #oldPassword="ngModel" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Current Password">

<input type="text" (keydown)='ngModelChange()' required class="form-control" id="newinputPassword" [(ngModel)]="passwordModel.newPassword" name="newPassword" #newPassword="ngModel" placeholder="New Password">
```

function

```
checkModelVal() {
  this.oldPw = this.passwordModel.oldPassword,
  this.newPw = this.passwordModel.newPassword;
  if (this.oldPw === this.newPw ) {
    console.log('new and old password can not be same');
  }
}
```

above code may be bad solution for the my requirement. if you know any better solution, please mention in the answer. thanks

Comment: Use reactive forms, add both fields to the same `formGroup` and add the custom validator to the group.

Comment: as @ritaj mention that can be read in the doc https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#reactive-form-validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want to display some kind of error and disable a submit button if the passwords are the same. You **don't** need to call the function each time a value has changed because the model is updated via **ngModel** and you always have them:

Your function is not bad but can be reduced to this:

```
checkModelVal() {
   return this.passwordModel.oldPassword !== this.passwordModel.newPassword;
}
```

Using this function you can handle the error messages, probably like this:

```
 <span *ngIf="!checkModelVal()">Passwords should be different</span>
```

and disable your submit button

```
  <button [disabled]="!checkModelVal()">Submit</button>
```

You can also make use of **Custom Validators** to make a **control** to be dependent on others. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40561221/angular-2-custom-validator-that-depends-on-another-form-control).

Good luck!

Comment: can i call checkModelVal, function in textbox keydown ?

Comment: You should look into reactive forms, which makes it easy to subscribe to value changes in form controls. https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms

Comment: @gihankumara Yes you can call the function in the input keydown but doesn't make any difference if you just check the difference.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewRadulescu

Answer (score 1):

This should help you figure it out...

Basically, since you didn't provide a button I assume you want to check if both passwords are equal on input change.

So, I inserted the `(change)` event in the `HTML` inputs (for more on the `(change)` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change).

With that in mind, I created an error message to be displayed when the inputs were the same.

Next, I created some `Javascript` functions to validate both input fields and a message to return the error messages.

Hope I helped! Have fun!

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <input type="text" required [(ngModel)]="passwordModel.oldPassword" 
name="oldPassword" #oldPassword class="form-control" id="inputPassword" 
placeholder="Current Password" (change)="checkOldPassword(oldPassword.value)">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12">
    <input type="text" required class="form-control" id="newinputPassword" 
[(ngModel)]="passwordModel.newPassword" name="newPassword" #newPassword
placeholder="New Password" (change)="checkNewPassword(newPassword.value)">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12" *ngIf="isNewPasswordInvalid">
    <small>{{getErrorMessage()}}</small>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
isNewPasswordInvalid: boolean = false;
message: string = "The new password can't be the same as the old password!";

function checkOldPassword(value){
  if(value === this.passwordModel.newPassword){
    this.inputInvalid();
  } else {
    this.inputValid();
  }
}

function checkNewPassword(value){
  if(value === this.passwordModel.oldPassword){
    this.inputInvalid();
  } else {
    this.inputValid();
  }
}

function inputInvalid(){
  document.getElementById('newinputPassword').style['border-color'] = 'red';
  this.isNewPasswordInvalid= true;
}

function inputValid(){
  document.getElementById('newinputPassword').style['border-color'] = '';
  this.isNewPasswordInvalid= false;
}

function getErrorMessage(){
  return this.message;
}
```

EDIT: In case you need a button, @Andrew Radulescu's answer will do the trick. Good luck!